# Description text for 404 errors headers - changing 'Not Found'

Tags: http, header, http-status-code-404

This question was asked many times before, but I wanted to ask about different aspect of it.
My testcase:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); // and
header("HTTP/1.0 404");
```

result in server returing header:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

But it's also possible to do:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Oh... sorry, did not find");
```

Where is this possibility coming from? Is it proper (does not make any complications?) to change `Not Found` string?

It's not that I want to change it as none will ever see it except for somone checking headers. But I'm courious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather not. This header is standarized and should be always returned as is - in the common form:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

If you need to pass any additional info to the client, pass it in the responses body and in standarized way as well, e.g.:

```
{
   "status": 404,
   "code": 509, //some internal code
   "message": "Can not find resource for ID: XXX"
}
```

Comment: I don't need. Was just wondering theoretically if it would be valid. Thank you for answer.